# Recepción vacía enviando variables POST a otro servidor con cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

Necesito enviar variables POST recibidas por un formulario en un servidor a otro servidor.

Tengo un archivo que recibe las variables y las agrupa en una matriz así:

```
<?php
$url = "http://servidor2.com/cotizador.php";
$datosProducto = array("modelo"=>htmlspecialchars($_GET["modelo"]), "fecha"=>$fecha, "nombre"=>htmlspecialchars($_POST["nombreCotizador"]), "email"=>htmlspecialchars($_POST["correoCotizador"]), "telefono"=>htmlspecialchars($_POST["telefonoCotizador"]), "mensaje"=>htmlspecialchars($_POST["mensajeCotizador"]));
$crm = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datosProducto);
$respuesta = curl_exec($crm);
if ($respuesta === FALSE){
echo "Error: ".curl_error($crm);
}
curl_close($crm);
var_dump($respuesta);
```

Y tengo un archivo que debe recibir e la matriz enviada con cURL así:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

El problema es que la respuesta en el archivo de envío muestra el resultado como si se hubiera enviado la matriz, sin embargo en el archivo receptor siempre muestra una matriz vacía.

Comment: ¿Te importaría activar la recepción de las cabeceras HTTP en la variable `$respuesta`? Es para confirmar si estás recibiendo un código HTTP 100 (*continue*) en vez del 200 (*ok*). Hazlo con un `curl_setopt($crm, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debería funcionar correctamente, por lo que es muy probable que el servidor web que estás contactando te esté respondiendo con un [código HTTP `100 continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100):

> Para que un servidor verifique los encabezados de la solicitud, un cliente debe enviar `Expect: 100-continue` como encabezado en su solicitud inicial y recibe un código de estado `100 Continue` en respuesta antes de enviar el cuerpo.

Es decir, tu código debería incluir el envío de dicha cabecera HTTP para que funcione adecuadamente:

```
<?php
$url = "http://servidor2.com/cotizador.php";
$crm = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crm, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crm, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crm, CURLOPT_POST, true);
/* Enviamos la cabecera HTTP que necesita el servidor web */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Expect: 100-continue",
]);
curl_setopt($crm, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    "modelo" => $_GET["modelo"],
    "fecha" => date('Y-m-d'),
    "nombre" => $_POST["nombreCotizador"],
    "email" => $_POST["correoCotizador"],
    "telefono" => $_POST["telefonoCotizador"],
    "mensaje" => $_POST["mensajeCotizador"],
]);
$respuesta = curl_exec($crm);
if ($respuesta === false) {
    echo "Error: ", curl_error($crm);
    exit();
}
var_dump($respuesta);
```

Otras notas:

- No uses `htmlspecialchars()` para codificar los datos enviados en el formulario, PHP se encargará de codificarlos adecuadamente.
- Las opciones `CURLOPT_POST` y `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` esperan valores booleanos (`true`) como parámetro, por lo que es mejor usar `true` en vez del número `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Estas enviando de manera incorrecta los parámetros se deben enviar como una cadena no un arreglo.

Usa:

```
<?php
$url = "http://servidor2.com/cotizador.php";
$datosProducto =  "modelo="  . urlencode($_GET["modelo"]) . "&" .
                  "fecha="   . urlencode($fecha) . "&" .
                  "nombre="  . urlencode($_POST["nombreCotizador"]) . "&" .
                  "email="   . urlencode($_POST["correoCotizador"]) . "&" .
                  "telefono=". urlencode($_POST["telefonoCotizador"]) . "&" .
                  "mensaje=" . urlencode($_POST["mensajeCotizador"]);

$crm = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crm, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datosProducto);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // si deseas recibir el resultado como un string la respuesta de la pagina consultada aqui por que esperas solo exito o false lo pongo pr si lo necesitas
$respuesta = curl_exec($crm);
if ($respuesta === FALSE) {
  echo "Error: ".curl_error($crm);
}

curl_close($crm); var_dump($respuesta);
```

Comment: Hola sergio, gracias por tu respuesta, he modificado mi codigo como lo indicas, pero sigue sin funcionar, ahora tu codigo me genera ciertas dudas: 1. Creas una variable $datos Con una función implode(), pero no la utilizas en el resto del codigo. 2. Agregas la linea CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 pero indicas una varible $curl (probe el codigo de las dos maneras como lo envias y colocando esta varible como $crm)

Comment: Es correcto tenia errores el codigo disculpa y datos debe enviarse en el **curl_setopt ($crm, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datos);**

Comment: De nuevo gracias Sergio, hice la modificación pero sigue sin funcionar, ahora el php me genera este Warning: PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in...

Comment: @SergioCauich , estás equivocado. El parámetro `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` de [`curl_setopt()`](https://php.net/es/curl_setopt) permite recibir una matriz con los valores del formulario. PHP se encargará de codificarlos adecuadamente en `multipart/form-data` que, a su vez, son interpretados sin problemas por PHP para entregar los valores en la variable superglobal `$_POST`.