# Recuperar variables enviadas con curl a una url externa

Tags: php, curl, yii2, yii

Tengo dos aplicaciones, la que proporciona las variables para validar que es un usuario con acceso válido, en yii1.1 alojada en su [www.web1.com](http://www.web1.com) y dentro de esta, opciones de menú que van a una nueva app hecha en yii2 que tendrá su dominio [www.web2.com](http://www.web2.com) en la cual debo recuperar las variables enviadas por post de web1.  Estoy enviando las variables ::

```html
    public function actionSend(){
        if(Yii::app()->user->getCurrInstSettings('has_gxd')){
      
            $url = 'http://web2.com/index.php?r=site';
            $host = "http://web2.com/index.php";
            
            $postData['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $postData['institution_id'] = $_SESSION['institution_id'];


            $ch = curl_init($host);
            $data = http_build_query($postData);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '123345456:correo@gmail.com');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $postData);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            
       return $this->redirect($url);
            

           
        }
        
    }
```

Pero no sé de qué manera recuperarlas en mi controller de web2, en la actionIndex del controller probé de todas las maneras en que se puede ver en el código y no consigo recuperar las variables.
¿Cómo se obtienen los parámetros enviados por curl?

¿Hay otra manera mas segura de hacer esto que no sea usando token?

```html
public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($_REQUEST);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET);
        
echo "con eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee <br>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r(get_headers($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ));
echo "server<br>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SERVER);


echo "serveyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyr<br>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r(http_build_query($_REQUEST));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($_ENV);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué retornas esto: `return $this->redirect($url);` y no `$response`?

Comment: @A.Cedano  para redireccionar a la url que le estoy indicando, sin embargo sustituí return $this->redirect($response);  y me lanza el error 2021/03/04 14:33:14 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] CHttpException: El sistema no ha podido encontrar la acción "No input file specified." solicitada. in /home/vagrant/www/classroomtv/protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/web/CController.php:483
Stack trace:
...REQUEST_URI=/admin/default/No%20input%20file%20specified.
HTTP_REFERER=http://web1/send

Comment: No entiendo mucho... tampoco uso Yii ni sé cómo funciona, pero, ¿para qué es el cURL y dónde obtienes los datos que éste te trae? Por eso me extrañó que no estuvieras retornando la respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo de curl lo tomé de otro post de aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112092/varibles-post-a-otro-servicor-con-curl   ya que las variables deben llegar a otra url y no pueden ir en la url en si, deben viajar por post, no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer eso

Comment: Sigo sin entender el problema. Parecería que quieres pasar datos de una web a otra ¿? Hay varias formas de hacer eso, por cURL, o programando una API en la web donde están los datos y solicitándolos desde la otra web. Da igual el estilo o método que tengas que usar, con tal de que sea válido. Lo que interesa aquí es que expliques con claridad las cosas para que podamos ayudarte. Sin entender el problema solamente se podría, quizá, divagar buscando una solución, pero nada más. Es preciso que entiendas el problema (el planteamiento del mismo) antes de poder resolverlo.